# Sublime text 3 format/covert one single line into multiple lines

Tags: javascript, css, sublimetext3

I have a fancybox CSS and JS that are in one single line and it is hard to read the code that way, but i can't find nothing about format/convert it into multiple lines nicely indented. Must be easy...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Answer (score 2):

you can use `JsPrettier` to format js code, and `CSS Format` to format css code.

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JsPrettier

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CSS%20Format

Comment: Oh ok so it's not a build in feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called a beautifier.

There are lots of sublime text packages named `BeautifyXXX`, where XXX is the language.

You can use online services to beautify code if it's only one-shot and you're code is not too sensible, too.